# Extract binary data from Spark dataframe in Java

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-java

I have a dataframe with below schema

```
root
 |-- blob: binary (nullable = true)
```

Data looks like below

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|blob                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[1F 8B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7B C0 C8 F0 EA 1D E3 FC C6 E6 7B 8C B3 DA F7 31 4E EB 3B 94 9C 9F AB 97 98 9B 58 95 9F A7 97 59 92 9A 1B 9F 9B 58 5C 92 5A A4 17 94 9A 93 58 92 99 9F 57 9C 91 59 10 1F 90 58 94 9A 57 12 1F 92 1F EF 9C 91 99 93 12 1F 9E 59 92 11 EF 92 9A 53 92 E8 60 A8 67 D0 99 92 9F 9B 98 99 17 9F 99 D2 0E 36 21 33 A5 A7 2C B5 A8 18 A8 39 BE 24 33 37 B5 AF 2F 37 B1 28 3B B5 A4 20 27 31 39 15 28 D9 5B 5C 9A 94 9B 59 0C 96 CF 4C E9 9B 9C 0C 36 B2 08 C9 BE E2 77 9B 1A BB EE AD EB 56 52 DF D5 D3 E5 64 60 69 66 EC E5 11 10 16 D4 AA C8 D4 9B DD C0 FF B4 75 4E C7 94 BE C3 4C 8B FA 94 BA B3 FB D5 98 98 8B 9F DE D1 9A 70 01 00 F6 9B E3 17 DA 00 00 00]|
```

I want to use map function on dataframe to read this column value and perform some action.

d.map(relationshipMapFunction, encoder)

where in `relationshipMapFunction` I am trying to extract the above blob.

```
public class RelationshipMapFunction implements MapFunction<Row, String> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6766320395808127072L;
    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(JobRunner.class);

    @Override
    public String call(Row row) throws Exception {
        // Code to read binary data and perform some actions

    }
}
```

How do I extract the byte array from `row` variable in the call method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to do it, but which one is best depends on your requirements. Let's see some of them.

### Map function with Dataframe

To follow the code you showed, and then extract the byte array directly from an object of type Row you can use the [`getAs(int)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html#getAs-int-) method of the `Row` class:

```
public class RelationshipMapFunction implements MapFunction<Row, String> {
    @Override
    public String call(Row row) throws Exception {
        final byte[] blob = row.<byte[]>getAs(0); // 0 is the index of the blob column in the dataframe
        return transformBlob(blob);
    }
}
```

and then you can use it with your Dataframe:

```
Dataset<String> mappedDs = df.map(new RelationshipMapFunction(), Encoders.STRING());
```

### Map function with typed Dataset

You can use an encoder to transform your Dataframe into a typed Dataset, for example if your Dataframe contains only a column of type `byte[]` you can directly use the `Encoders.BINARY()`. In this case the map function will receive an object of type `byte[]` instead of `Row`.

```
public class RelationshipMapFunction implements MapFunction<byte[], String> {
    @Override
    public String call(byte[] blob) {
        return transformBlob(blob);
    }
}
```

and then you can use it with your Dataframe, after applying an encoder:

```
Dataset<String> mappedDs = df
    .as(Encoders.BINARY())
    .map(new RelationshipMapFunction(), Encoders.STRING());
```

---

In both cases, if the map function is simple you can replace it with a lambda.

Other options include the use of UDFs.

Note that if the transformation you need to apply is as simple as decoding an UTF8 String from the byte array, you can use Spark SQL functions directly (a cast from binary to string will do the job).

Comment: Ended up with similar solution using `byte[] attrValBytes = (byte[]) r.get(0);` to fetch the byte array. Thanks !